# How can i store my highscore somewhere so that I can use them to purchase from store? How do I mange my total score and high score

Tags: java, android

This is my gameover java code. How can I save my high score so that it shows when I relaunch the activity. I used sharedprefrences which works but it doesn't store my high score whenever I play it again Closed.
How can I modify my code to permanently store all attempts ? How can I determine the all-time high score? After each run of the program, I would like it to remind me "what is the all-time high score".
.

```
 package com. example.myantkillergame;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    public class GAMEOVER extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageButton imgbtn;
     TextView  totalscore,indv1,indv2,indv3,indv4,indv5,indv6,indv7,indv8,higscore;
          @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_g_a_m_e_o_v_e_r);
    
    
    
            int value1 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("score1");
            int value2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("score2");
            int value3 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("score3");
            int value4 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("score4")
            int value5 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("score5");
            int value6 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("score6");
            int value7 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("score7");
            int value8 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("score8");
            totalscore=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoretotal) ;
           int score_count = getIntent().getIntExtra("m",0);
           totalscore.setText(score_count + "");
    higscore=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.highscorelabel);
    SharedPreferences setting= getSharedPreferences("GAME DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highscore=setting.getInt("HIGH_SCORE :",0);
    if (score_count > highscore){
        higscore.setText("HIGHSCORE :" + score_count);
        //save
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=setting.edit();
        editor.putInt("HIGH_SCORE",score_count);
        editor.commit();
    
    }else{
        higscore.setText("HIGHSCORE :" + highscore);
    }
    
    
        indv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.antone) ;
           indv1.setText(value1+"");
            indv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.anttwo) ;
            indv2.setText(value2+"");
            indv3=findViewById(R.id.antthree) ;
            indv3.setText(value3+"");
            indv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.antfour) ;
            indv4.setText(value4+"");
            indv5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.antfive) ;
            indv5.setText(value5+"");
            indv6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.antsix) ;
            indv6.setText(value6+"");
            indv7=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.antseven) ;
            indv7.setText(value7+"");
            indv8=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.anteight) ;
            indv8.setText(value8+"");
            imgbtn= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnbackgameover);
            imgbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    btnback();
                }
            });
        }
        public void btnback(){
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        
        public void try again(View view)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Selection.class));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can create an XML file locally and edit and read it whenever required.

Comment: I wouldn't create an **XML** file just for that. You can have a public variable to store whatever you want. You can also use `SharedPreferences` if you want to keep them even when you close the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Android Shared Preferences`. Shared Preferences are saved in the app folder in the device storage and are accessible only by the application.

Reference Documentations: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Trainings: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences